# Problem in using @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas to signature on images

Tags: react-native, react-native-sketch-canvas

I using `@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas` to signature on images. Put images in path `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` and put images in slide.when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
error while updating property 'localSoureImage' of a View managed by RNSketchCanvs
null
Failed to allocate a 6215100 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
```

[image]

Sample of image path:

```json
localSourceImage = {
  filename: 'frontcar.jpg',
  directory: '',
  mode: 'AspectFit',
  includeImage: true,
  cropToImageSize: true
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localSourceImage` has only 3 props: `filename`, `directory` and `mode`. `IncludeImage` and `cropToImageSize` are properties of `SavePreference` object.

`SavePreference` Object:

```
{
  folder: 'RNSketchCanvas',
  filename: 'image',
  transparent: true,
  imageType: 'jpg',
  includeImage: true,
  includeText: false,
  cropToImageSize: true
}
```

Local source Image

```
{
  filename: 'image.png',  
  directory: '',
  mode: 'AspectFill'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a completely different issue with @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas but I ended up switching to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sketch. Not sure if this will solve your specific issue, though.

Comment: tnx a lot Rory . but react-native-sketch pakage can't meet my need.i want drawing signature on image that is sketch background.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @NiloufarRezaee with code snippet, I'm also facing same issue as yours.